# AWS Sagemaker training job stuck in progress state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a training job yesterday, same as usual, just adding few more training data. I didn't have any problem with this in the last 2 years (the same exact procedure and code). This time after 14 hours more or less simply stalled.
Training job is still "in processing", but cloudwatch is not logging anything since then. Right now 8 more hours passed and no new entry is in the logs, no errors no crash.
Can someone explain this ? Unfortunately I don't have any AWS support plan.
As you can see from the picture below after 11am there is nothing..

[image]

The training job is supposed to complete in the next couple of hours, but now I'm not sure if is actually running (in this case would be a cloudwatch problem) or not..

**UPDATE**

Suddenly the training job failed, without any further log. The reason is

> ClientError: Artifact upload failed:Error 7: The credentials received
> have been expired

But there is still nothing in the logs after 11am. Very weird.

Comment: Is this on a managed SageMaker instance, or on an EC2 machine?

Comment: It's a managed SageMaker instance, tf1.12 py36. Anyway I tried to re-launch the same training job, with the same data and went smooth .. so it was AWS fault, but don't know how to report that since I don't have any support plan and on the dev forum noboby cares..

Comment: No worries - rare that I've seen it, but on one or two occasions, just restarting the instance has fixed it in my experience. Glad you got it fixed, thanks for replying :-)

Comment: But how did you manage to monitor the accuracy and loss metrics? I can't visualise them when training a subset of my data for one epoch. Also, what is the difference between GPUUtilization and GPUMemoryUtilization? I have a high GPUMemoryUtilization but the GPUUtilization is a flat zero graph for me. I am using a ml.g4dn.xlarge instance, which has 1 GPU.

Comment: When you create a training job you can define metrics with regex, cloudwatch will grab from the logs the values according to the regex. It's not that precise because it's time-based and text-grabbing, but can give you an estimation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers I can confirm that is something that can happen very rarely (I' haven't experienced it anymore since then), but it's AWS fault. Same data, same algorithm.